# Prolog Query Duplicates

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof, prolog-tabling

I've seen a few questions on this topic, however none of them really answers my question properly. I'll write a small example, here are some facts:

```
football(john).
football(sam).

tennis(john).
tennis(pete).

netball(sandy).
```

I want to create a rule that states `pete` likes anyone that plays football or tennis.

```
likes(pete, X) :- (football(X) ; tennis(X)), X \= pete.
```

But obviously when I query it in Prolog, `john` will come up twice as `john` plays both football and tennis. I want it to come up with `john` only once. How can I amend my code to do that?

Thanks in advance - Dan

Comment: The only real way to do it is with `setof/3`. This is because Prolog doesn't keep state between solutions, so it literally doesn't know that it has already given you john once before—unless you make it keep track using a second-order predicate like `setof/3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One clean solution is to use your Prolog system's **tabling** mechanism.

For example, in SWI-Prolog, you can do this by adding the following directive at the top :

```
:- table likes/2.
```

With this directive, you get:

```
?- likes(pete, X).
X = john ;
X = sam.
```

Whereas without it, you get:

```
?- likes(pete, X).
X = john ;
X = sam ;
X = john.
```

Tabling is also known as **SLG resolution**.

Comment: The code in the question had a trivial, but hard-to-find error (`x` vs `X`) which was clearly unintentional and obfuscated the question. I took the liberty to adapt your code, ok?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach mentioned by @DanielLyons in his comment to your question.

It is based on [prolog-setof](/questions/tagged/prolog-setof), so it is portable across different Prolog systems.

Using SICStus Prolog 4.5.0:

```
| ?- setof(t, likes(pete,X), _).
X = john ? ;
X = sam ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog offers library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences))

```
likes(pete, X) :- distinct( ((football(X) ; tennis(X)), X \= pete) ).

?- likes(pete, X).
X = john ;
X = sam ;
false.
```

It's built on the infrastructure that make tabling available, tough, so it has similar requirements on memory storage.